# AWS Lambda: failed with error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/lambda_function.py

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, chmod

I have the following CI/CD setup with Gitlab for deploying my lambda function

[image]

When it runs no error happens but when I try executing the function I receive the "failed with error [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/task/lambda_function.py" error. Is there any way to solve this? I've found [this](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/troubleshooting-deployment.html) article in which aws suggests using chmod to give file permissions, but it didn't help.

BTW: I've ran the same commands locally in my machine and no error happens when running the function

Thanks in advance for any answer.

UPDATE: CloudWatch Logs below

[image]

Comment: The error occurs when you invoke your function or when you are executing the update-function-code?

Comment: Whenever I invoke the function. The update-function-code happens normally

Comment: Can you check CloudWatch Logs for possibly more error messages?

Comment: Just updated it

Comment: This is a similar question. You can check out my answer here!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68037739/11839249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have similar trouble like [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-api-gateway-url-shortener) one and another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46076543/permission-denied-after-uploading-aws-lambda-python-zip-from-s3) on stackoverflow as well.
You have to manually set the permissions of the zip file.

quoting from the bug

> The zip archive preserves file permissions, so if you have a 644
> permissions file, deflate it and inflate it back up, you get 644
> permissions for that file.
>
> So to fix the issue, simply set the expected permissions
> before deflation, in Lambda's case, something like 755 will do.